# Socket.io, server not responding to connection event

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cloudways

I have a managed server at cloudways. I am trying to use socket.io.

**client.php:**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
console.log(socket);
```

**server.js:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('is connected');
});
```

When visiting the page, I see two instances of 200 OK in the network section of the console.
The console in the browser also prints the socket variable, which has "connected : true".

However, I DO NOT see "is connected" in the terminal (from server.js), it is just blank.

This site has worked locally, but these problems are appearing when trying to get it to work at Cloudways.

Any ideas?

I have tried switching "localhost" to both the domain name and the IP-address, and I have tried different ports, but 3000 is the only one that will let me start the server.js without error.

[image]

**EDIT**

Cloudways have confirmed that port 3000 should be used.

I have tried changing the url in io() to:

```
var socket = io('http://my-cloudways-url:3000'); (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
var socket = io('http://www.my-domain.club:3000'); (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
var socket = io('http://ip-adr:3000'); (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
```

And today I am getting

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000'); (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

I have also tried io.connect(using the same adresses / ports).

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but when doing this I just get "404" (not found) errors in the console when trying to create the socket.

Comment: Do you tried to install the socket.io package with npm in your terminal (cloud)?

Comment: Yes, installed through npm

Comment: try to put your url inside the connect... I think maybe you can use express for req the correctly hostname

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is your php index... Because you are setting the localhost and the port.

I'm not sure about how Cloudway works. But, when we run the server.js, some clouds give some url for access our projects...

**In your cloudways try to use the official URL that they given to you access the project:**

```
var socket = io.connect('url.from.cloudway');
```

**For example, I'm using cloud9, and when I execute the server.js, return one url like:**

```
Your code is running: https://demo-some-id.c9.io
```

And when I'm using socket.io, I need to set in my index the URL parameter inside the IO.

```
var socket = io('https://demo-some-id.c9.io');
```

You need to add the client-side socket.io.js [version](https://gist.github.com/MatthiasHoldorf/7957556) and add the script tag with the path, like:

```
<script src="js/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Obs.: Some clouds, you need to set the url in your `<script>` tag

```
<script src="https://demo-some-id.c9.io/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried changing to var socket = io('http://phpstack-19684-309697.cloudwaysapps.com:3000'); That gives me "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: Yes, I did use http:// . seems it was edited out somehow. If I type the url here, the http:// is removed

Comment: It seems like your problem is with the url inside your io connect

Comment: Try to use https:// in your url, or try to use with any value inside the io, like var socket = io();. In this case, in your CloudWay account

Comment: I have tried with both http, https, different values for the url and also no url like io();. None of those have helped me unfortunately, and they have all returned error messages. This solution is the only one I have found that does not give an error message in the console, but still it will not register the connection on the server side.

Comment: Try to set the port to 80, some clouds just support specifics ports. In this case in your cloudWay... In this case add inside your script tag (client.php) the url... like my exmaple

Comment: I think ports below 1024 are "privileged" ports that I can not listen on as I am not root on this server. I tried port 80, get 404 error

Comment: If I try to listen to port 80, the server.js file will not run

Comment: Are you added the client side socket.io.js?

Comment: Yes I am referencing that

Comment: Can you test with your url? https://demo-id.c9.io/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151538/discussion-between-sayuri-mizuguchi-and-bergkamp10).